# let $f_n(x) = \frac{x^ n}{n!}$ and $f(x) = \sum f_n(x)$, prove with the Beppo-Levi theorem that:

Tags: integration, measure-theory

let $f_n(x) = \frac{x^ n}{n!}$ and $f(x) = \sum f_n(x)$, prove with the Beppo-Levi theorem that:

$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dm(x) = \sum \int_{a}^{b} f_n(x) dm(x)$

if we use Beppo levi, this equation follows because $f_n(x)$ is continuous hence measurable. The only problem is that the beppo levi theorem requires positive measurable functions, which f_n(x) isn't.

2) I need to prove that the right side of the equation is $f(b) - f(a)$ as well. The main problem here is that i get a '+1' term at f(b) - f(a) and not at the right side term.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i assumed at 2 that 0! = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand side is $\int_a^b e^x\, dm(x) = e^b - e^a$, and the right hand side is \begin{align}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\int_a^b x^n\, dm(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b^{n+1} - a^{n+1}}{n!(n+1)}\\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{b^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} - \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\\
&= (e^b - 1) - (e^a - 1)\\
&= e^b - e^a
\end{align}

Therefore $\int_a^b f(x)\, dm(x) = \sum \int_a^b f_n(x)\, dm(x)$.

Comment: omg, i made a mistake with the brackets -_-, thanks though! Any idea about the beginning?

Comment: Show that $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \int_a^b |f_n(x)|\, dm(x) < \infty$.

Comment: that makes no sense to me, why does this imply that that the $f_n(x)'s$ are positive measurable functions? Or are you using an other theorem to prove this equality than the beppo levi theorem?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Kess you're misunderstanding. You can't prove that the $f_n$ are positive measurable functions because they are not positive on $\Bbb R$ (although they are positive on $(0, \infty)$). It seems that you were given a weaker form of Beppo Levi theorem, but this [version](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524323/bepo-levi-implies-monotonone-convergence-theorem) is the one I'm hinting at.